# VSCode: Hiding elements in Status Bar

Tags: visual-studio-code

[image]

I am trying to use custom CSS to hide the following from the status bar in VSCode:

1. The git branch
2. The python element

I've followed the instructions

I tried setting the following but to no avail:

```
 .statusbar-item.left .octicon.octicon-git-branch,
 .statusbar-item.left .octicon.octicon-sync
{
  display: none !important;
}
```

I followed the steps outlined here: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/3874#issuecomment-404161826

I obtained the CSS names from this file:

https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/blob/master/test/smoke/src/areas/statusbar/statusbar.ts

Can someone please point out why my settings are not working?

Answer (score 2):

vscode 1.36 added the ability to hide status bar elements, see [v1.36 release notes, hiding individual status bar items](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_36#_hide-individual-status-bar-items).  Right-click on the status bar itself to see a list of items that can be hidden or revealed.  (including the git branch, etc.)